# EMI difference between Ferrite (powdered iron) and Iron

Tags: emc, magnetics

In an EMI application where I'm applying a snap on style ferrite core around a cable.  What's the difference / benefit of the typical powdered iron type and just using a similarly sized piece of iron with a hole in it?

I could see where it would be easier to manufacture a powdered core and maybe more rust resistant?  I don't know what the electrical differences are.

Comment: Is your question about the material or just about the shape?

Comment: Ferrite is not actually the same thing as powdered iron

Comment: It was about the material

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> using a similarly sized piece of iron with a hole in it?

Well, the whole point about ferrites and iron powder is that the mixture is fairly non-conducting so when a wanted AC current passes through the core there are insignificant eddy current losses due to the bulk conduction.

Think about what an AC transformer uses - it uses laminates of steel (aka a type of iron) and it does so because the laminates are largely insulated from each other by a lacquer. If a transformer used a big lump of iron or steel for a core, that core would represent a shorted turn and render the thing useless.

As frequency rises, the laminates have to get thinner to avoid greater eddy current loss and the natural progression is to use powdered iron or ferrite. Having said that, at a few MHz, most high-permeability ferrites are poor because of induced eddy current loss but that is the crux of the EMI prevention - at high frequencies there is eddy current conduction through millions of little particles and this phenomena can turn a ferrite bead into a good attenuator of unwanted frequencies.